# C# replace string if string has other characters from both ends

Tags: c#, replace

I want to replace a string if it is a part of another string from both ends.

Say for example a string +35343+3566. I want to replace +35 with 0 only if it is surrounded with characters from both sides. So desired outcome would be +35343066.

Normally I'd use `line.Replace("+35", "0")` and perhaps `if-else` to meet a condition

```
string a = "+35343+3566";

string b = a.Replace("+35", "0");
```

I would want 'b = +35343066 and not b = 0343066`

Comment: are you sure 'a' is an integer ?

Comment: If you would have run this code *even once*, you would have seen that after line *2*, **`b`** equals `"38909"` because the addition statement in line *1* has been executed. See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9jEHMN

Comment: `a` should be as `string` in your code. please verify and correct it to get answers!!

Comment: Apologies. Edited it.

Comment: is this a home work or what is the idea behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex for this. For example:

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace("+35343+3566", "(?<=.)(\\+35)(?=.)", "0");
// replaced will contain +35343066
```

So what this pattern is saying is that +35 `(\\+35)` must have one character behind `(?<=.)` and one character ahead `(?=.)`

Comment: note that `\\+35` in second argument does not require to be placed inside parenthesis since we don't need to capture it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a Regular Expression, as follows:

```
string a = "+35343+3566";

var regex = new Regex(@"(.)\+35(.)"); // look for "+35" between any 2 characters, while remembering the characters that were found in ${1} and ${2}
string b = regex.Replace(a, "${1}0${2}"); // replace all occurences with "0" surrounded by both characters that were found
```

See Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OdCKsy

---

Or slightly simpler, if it turns out that only the prefix character matters:

```
string a = "+35343+3566";

var regex = new Regex(@"(.)\+35"); // look for a character followed by "+35", while remembering the character that was found in ${1}
string b = regex.Replace(a, "${1}0"); // replace all occurences with the character that was found followed by a 0
```

See Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9jEHMN